# Showing a jquery price list according to users' country

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm a front end developer and what I'm trying to do with a client's website is this: I want to create two different price lists on a unique page. I'll be doing them in jquery and css.
I want that users from Italy will see price list n°1 and users from Spain will see price list n°2.

It's imperative that an Italian user won't be able to give a look at the price list of Spanish users and viceversa.

Could you guy give me a hint on how I could accomplish that and, possibly, a couple of example lines?

Thanks everybody
best wishes

Comment: Which one will you show to users you're unsure about or who are in say, the USA?

Comment: This seems like a better fit for server side code

Comment: Are you looking for some JavaScript function to detect the [user's location](http://briancray.com/posts/find-web-visitors-location-javascript-google-api/)?

Comment: *"It's imperative that an Italian user won't be able to give a look at the price list of Spanish users and viceversa."* With that statemenet in mind, this should be done serverside.

Comment: Agree with @Kevin B, for the same reason you [can't do cryptography in javascript](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/), you can't guarantee that javascript can ever completely prevent someone from viewing something. Client side code is operating in a hostile environment.

Comment: This may be against European free trade law.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to define what Spanish and Italian means, more specifically how would you differentiate them.

You can check the browser setting (client side, but not accurate at all) or you can do IP geolocation. This is done server side and you can use different third party services.
If it is available you can use geolocation API on client side, but again not accurate, as on a desktop browser, user can easily change their location.

How would you do IP geolocation depends on the server side technology and the service used. You can do it on the client side using something like JSONP, but again not safe.

Not even IP geolocation will be fully-proof because users can use proxies from other countries.

Answer (score 0):

If the jQuery can see both versions, then so can an Italian or Spanish person by looking at the code.

Take a look at http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/mod_geoip2. With this module, you can have 2 different price lists on your server (or 3 - one for rest of world), and present the user with the right one for their country.